Why can't I see the "glow" caused by a UV light on my camera?
Background
I was looking at some rocks with a UV light when I saw small specs of the rock glow green. Curious I decided to take a closer look using my ANNLOV digital microscope (what I'm hoping is classified as a camera by users of this exchange). No matter what I tried to do I could not get the nice green glow to apear on the screen. Instdead I had a semi uniform darkish blue hue with a few reflective spots.
I tried with another rock showing containing a decent sized chunk that glowed yellowish and again I could not see it on the screen.
Pondering and doing a little research I can think of two reasons. One the UV light I using was too weak to be captured (unlikely) and two the camera has a filter for UV light (more probable) preventing the glow from being captured.
Question
Why would I be able to see a glow caused by UV light with the naked eye and not be able to capture it using a digital camera?
Additional Info
I very confident that I was pointing the digital camera at the correct location (on the first sample). Because under normal light I was able to zoom in and see tiny clear green rods embeded in the rock (same shape as the glow).
"Most digital cameras have a UV blocking filter over the imaging sensor..."
-reddit: How to view UV Light? (reason why I hypothesize that my  has a UV filter.

I vote it's all in the shadow of the lens of the microscope.  Unless your UV light is a first-party attachment of the microscope setup.

I think I understand but you could elaborate on "... in the shadow of the lens of the microscope."

In addition to the UV light reflecting into the lens which could affect the sensor exposure, some UV cut filters actually flouresce a little: both mess with contrast etc. It is unclear if the microscope even has a UV cut filter, but probably it does (most digital sensors are sensitive to UV and IR so they have built-in cut filters). However, it is traditional when doing UV fluorescence photos to have a UV cut filter so only visible wavelengths make it into the lens. Source: myself as I routinely shoot fine art under UV.  see, for example https://repositorio.ucp.pt/handle/10400.14/38761

also, use UV eye protection when doing this.

@Tolure I'm assuming the UV light is not on the microscope itself (that probably provides white light from LEDs).  The microscope may have to be pretty close to the subject so maybe it's in between the UV light and the subject at the point of magnification when you're using it.

another semi-obvious thought: the color you see may be outside the RGB gamut

If you are seeing distinct colors under UV light, you are not seeing UV light but fluorescence in the visible spectrum.  Fluorescence of minerals will typically be monochromatic, with an intensity focused on a single wavelength.  The colors in a rainbow are of that kind, and rainbows often have some appearance of unreal iridiscence in bands that just doesn't make it onto pictures of rainbows on paper or screen.  It's outside of the representable color space of those media.
A camera's color vision is different from a human's one: that's why we need white balance.  The camera will try to reconstruct something into sRGB color space that is supposed to look similar to the human eye as what it has been looking at.  That works better for some things than others.
And monochromatic ones are the worst.  While a camera does have UV filters, they usually are less discriminative than the human eye so the near-visible color band has a larger impact on the sensor than on human vision.  That means that the pure monochromatic color you want to be seeing is considerably watered down by what the camera still sees as something purplish while it doesn't faze your eyes.  The camera sees a lot more reflection of the UV light than it sees the fluorescence caused by it.  Your eyes adapt to the dark, your cameras sight doesn't.
You could probably improve your chances by using a photographic filter that cuts off inside the visible wavelengths, like below 450nm (the usual cutoff for UV filters is at 390nm).  That will somewhat impact color rendition but it will move the UV light into the dark for the camera and make it more likely that you can get a good look at greenish fluorescence without getting fazed by the UV light itself.

If the light is visible to the naked eye it is not UV light; it is reflected near UV light in the visible spectrum, and it is/should be visible to an imaging (camera) sensor.
But note that, to a very large extent, very low frequency wavelengths (near UV) will only be recorded by the blue filtered photosites. And only 25% of the sensor photosites are filtered for blue centric wavelengths... i.e. the sensor is less sensitive to them overall in terms of both exposure and spatial resolution.
The most likely answer is that either auto exposure (or auto white balance) is preventing the exposure/color difference from showing up.

Is there a way I could test to see if the issue is with either auto exposure or with auto white balance?

@Tolure, do you have any control over either?

Not yet, but that is why I'm doing research prior to going out and just buying what I hope would be a solution.

As you know, violet has the shortest wavelength that we humans can see with our naked eye. We humans can’t see UV light. What we see when turn-on a UV light source bluish violet, this is light energy in the visible range. In other words, UV lamps output visible violet and invisible UV light energy.
Now the shorter the wavelengths are the more energetic. Invisible UV plays on objects and this energy stimulates some materials causing them to output visible light. In other words, what you are seeing with your naked eye is visible light not UV light which is invisible.
That being said, the question is, why can’t you image with your camera the stunning visible light radiating from the UV illumined rock?
The answer could be many things: Our digital cameras are fine-tuned to yield a faithful image on a computer monitor. Perhaps this glowing output color is not compatible. Also, the ISO of film and digital sensors in computed based on the usual colors of ambient pictorial situations, your work is likely outside this realm.
If you are using flash, it surely overpowers the UV light source.
In other words, you guess is as good as mine.

Since it could be many things. What steps or experiments would you recommend so that I can narrow the field of possibilities down?

The first step - make a series of exposures at different f-number settings on manual.
